# Getting native vibration to work on iOS through AS3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, vibration

I've been looking at the documentation and it's a bit confusing as to how I even import the extension for the vibration plugin. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/vibration.html The instructions says I need to mess about with Xcode, but I thought the point of Adobe AIR was that you don't need to mess about with Xcode; it's really convoluted. How exactly do I import the class and files so that I can use the provided code in AS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read a this article: [Vibration native extension sample](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air/extensions/vibration.html)

click a this link: [Vibration Download](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/air/ane/Vibration.zip)

and unzip anywhere.

Click File-ActionScript 3.0 Settings

link to (In ReadyToUseExtension) **VibrationActionScriptLibrary.swc**, **com.adobe.extensions.Vibration.ane**

[image]

In Simulator not compiled. because Requested extension com.adobe.Vibration is not supported for MacOS-x86.

```
import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Vibration;

var vibe:Vibration;
if (Vibration.isSupported)
{
    vibe = new Vibration();
    vibe.vibrate(2000);
}
```

Comment: I linked to that article in my post. The steps it provides is what I was saying is convoluted and hard to understand... it's saying to make a class in Xcode, but should the classes in the zip file not be what you import?

Comment: I a little mistake. modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for putting it in a much more understandable format! I've got it all imported now. So I take it that basically, I won't be able to compile in Flash because of the vibration, so I'll have to keep testing on the device. I have the vibration logic in part of my program but it doesn't seem to work... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using the files in the `ReadyToUseExtension` directory, add the pre-packaged .ane file to your project, as [in this tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/using-ane-in-flash.html).