# Native vibration on iOS (iPhone 5) through AS3 causes crash

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, vibration

I'm trying to test the vibration on an iPhone but the vibration doesn't work when tested on the device. As soon as the application is run, it crashes (and closes) without vibrating. I've imported all relevant extensions and linked to the relevant Adobe AIR library classes as per [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777563/getting-native-vibration-to-work-on-ios-through-as3).

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import com.adobe.nativeExtensions.Vibration; 

    public class Test extends Sprite
    {
        public function Test()
        {
            run();
        }

        public function run(): void {
            var vibe:Vibration;
            if (Vibration.isSupported)
            {
                vibe = new Vibration();
                vibe.vibrate(25000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't used that ANE, but I've found some ANEs will crash an app if you attempt to use them on startup. Try waiting at least a few frames before calling the run() function.

Comment: I've tried putting run(); inside a TimerEvent.TIMER of 10 seconds. It runs fine up until the 10 seconds then crashes again like before.